# magento setup:upgrade enables module

Tags: magento-2.1, command-line, setup-upgrade

I've just created a Magento2 module, here is the module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_MyModule" setup_version="1.0.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

So nothing out of the ordinary. I also have a `InstallSchema.php` file and a `InstallData.php` file to add a custom attribute to Products, as well as the ResourceModel that goes along.

When I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then module gets installed, the new table is created. But the module is also **enabled** by default in `app/etc/config.php`.

Is this the standard behaviour? If so, how can one prevent it?

PS : I'm working on a dev environment.

Comment: i invite @BabyinMagento to answer this question.

Comment: also get add entry in `setup_module` table too.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I've been sport with him lately, I even offered a bounty on one of his questions ;) . Didn't quite get your latest comment

Comment: there is also add entry in `setup_module` when the module installed. with `schema_version` and `data_version`.

Comment: as far i remember in start of magento2 you have to add entry in `app/etc/config.php` to make the module work if you want to your module previous version then it is normal behavior. may be i am wrong but not sure on that

Comment: Well, the thing is, I didn't have to do any manipulation in either the DB or `app/etc.config.php` and yet my module is activated, hence the question.